# Can TIndyHTTP's POST method be called multiple times very quickly?

Tags: post, indy

I'm using Indy ver 10.5498 to post some multipart/form data including an attached file to an api. My code is adapted from that supplied to my by Remy in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768206/how-do-i-include-a-file-in-a-tidmultipartformdatastream-for-use-with-indy-idhttp/55875288?noredirect=1#comment98731340_55875288) post, with protocol error handling taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475319/accessing-json-data-after-indy-post).
The code I now have works well and I get a response back from the server with data about 2 seconds after making the post.

However on occasion I might need to do a post multiple times very quickly, for example by looping through the dataset returned from a database and doing a post for each record.

Is there anything I need to know or any special code I need to write in order to deal with the situation where I might be making a second POST before the first POST has completed sending (or at least before the server's response has been received? Or is the POST a blocking call that does not return control until the response is received?

At the moment the TIdHTTP component is placed on the form, not dynamically created. I could create a new TIdHTTP object for every post and destroy it afterwards if that's necessary.

The code I use to do the post at the moment is below

```
function TForm1.Upload(url: string; params, filenames: TStrings): string;
var
 FormData : TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
 ResponseText : string;
 i : integer;
begin
  FormData := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to params.Count - 1 do
      FormData.AddFormField(params.Names[i], params.ValueFromIndex[i]);
    for i := 0 to filenames.Count - 1 do
       FormData.AddFile('attachment', filenames[i]);   

    //add authorisation header
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization:Basic ' + U_generalStuff.base64encodeStr(ATHORISATION_STR));

    //way to use just one try except yet get the full text server response whether its a 400 error or a success response
    //see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475319/accessing-json-data-after-indy-post
    // Make sure it uses HTTP 1.1, not 1.0,  and disable EIdHTTPProtocolException on errors
    IdHTTP1.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
    IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions := IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions + [hoKeepOrigProtocol, hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];
    try
       ResponseText := IdHTTP1.Post(url, FormData);   //post to the api
    except
      on E: Exception do
         begin
         ResponseText := E.ClassName + ': ' + E.message;
         raise;
         end;
    end; //try-except
  finally
     result := ResponseText;
  end; //try finally
end;
```

I've since seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123765/how-to-use-threads-with-idhttp-in-delphi-10)   that talks about threading and using the parallel library. Is that something I should be investigating to answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most things in Indy, `TIdHTTP.Post()` is a *synchronous* operation.  It does not return back to the caller until the response has been received in full (or until an error occurs).  So, if you call `TIdHTTP.Post()` in a simple loop, you CANT send a new `POST` request until the previous request has fully completed.  If you need to do that, you will have to call `TIdHTTP.Post()` *asynchronously* by calling it in multiple worker threads (and give each thread its own `TIdHTTP` object, as you can't reuse a `TIdHTTP` object across multiple simultaneous requests).

Comment: Ok Thank you. Now I understand the behavior I can work with that.